# Create a column that calculates the percentage of the total value of the previous column

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, percentage

Below I have a query that gives me the monthly total by state, with the last column giving me the yearly total. I want to create a column that gives me the percentage of the total by state.

Here is what I already have

```
SELECT STATE, 
 ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-02-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS JAN_TOTALREV,
 ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-03-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS FEB_TOTALREV,
 ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-04-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS MAR_TOTALREV,
 ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-05-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS APR_TOTALREV,
 ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-06-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS MAY_TOTALREV,
 ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-07-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS JUN_TOTALREV,
 ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-08-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS JUL_TOTALREV,
 ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-09-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS AUG_TOTALREV,
 ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-10-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS SEP_TOTALREV,
 ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-11-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS OCT_TOTALREV,
 ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-12-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS NOV_TOTALREV,
 ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2023-01-07' THEN TNET END),0) AS DEC_TOTALREV,
 ROUND(SUM(TNET),0) AS YEAR_TOTALREV

  FROM [dbo].example]
    WHERE LOADDATE BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2023-01-31'
  GROUP BY STATE
```

Below is what I would like the last two columns to look like

| STATE | YEAR_TOTALREV | Column B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AL | 1000 | 10% |
| NE | 3000 | 30% |
| NY | 6000 | 60% |

Comment: So what are you stuck on?

Comment: Creating the code that would give me the percentages in column B

Comment: You could put what you have into a sub select, get the sum of the entire year, then divide each month by the sum.

Comment: Use a window function I e `sum over ()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by Dale K, we can compute the grand total of the sums of all states with window functions:

```
SELECT STATE, 
    ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN LOADDATE = '2022-02-07' THEN TNET END), 0) AS JAN_TOTALREV,
    . . .
    ROUND(SUM(TNET), 0) AS YEAR_TOTALREV,
    100.0 * SUM(TNET)
        / NULLIF(SUM(SUM(TNET)) OVER(), 0) AS PCT
FROM [dbo].example]
WHERE LOADDATE BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2023-01-31'
GROUP BY STATE
```